# How to use netBeans debugger to run for an amount of time

Tags: debugging, netbeans

I rarely used the netbeans debugger but I have this bug in my program which I'm trying to get to the bottom of. Basically my program searches a binary file (4.5gb) for a seqeunce of bytes and writes it to file. However, the programm always stalls at this specific point in the file when reading near halfway of the file (~2gb). They way I using the debugger if putting a breakpoint and keep "continuing" the debugger until it reaches that point in the file but it's going to take forever to reach the 2gb mark. I'm guessing there's a better way to use the debugger which I'm not aware of. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans supports conditional breakpoints. If you add a breakpoint via the menu "Debug / New Breakpoint" (or just hit Ctrl+Shift+F8) you can specify a condition (either how often the breakpoint has to be hit until it execution is halted on this breakpoint or [an expression](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqDebuggingConditionalBreakpoints)).

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a count of how much data you have processed, and add an if() block which checks whether you are up to the 2GB mark. Put a dummy command inside the if() block, and add a breakpoint on the dummy command; this will only be reached when you have processed sufficient data.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, it just skips over the if statement everytime when it is less than 2gb